# How to remove milliseconds and corrospndent data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

Hello everyone I am new to pandas i have an ecg signal that has hundred thousands of rows because it mesurments are taken every milli second. thus i want to modify the data to make it in seconds and removing the milliseconds and their corrospondent ECG signal.

```
                 Time    ECG1   ECG2
2020-10-09 15:55:49.004 -5.19   -5.19
2020-10-09 15:55:49.008 -5.19   -5.19
2020-10-09 15:55:49.012 -5.19   -5.19
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the desired output dataframe

Comment: 2020-10-09 15:55:49  -5.19   -5.19
2020-10-09 15:55:50  -5.19   -5.19
2020-10-09 15:55:51  -5.19   -5.19

Answer (score 0):

First I recreate your df

```
d={'Time':['2020-10-09 15:55:49.004' , '2020-10-09 15:55:49.008', '2020-10-09 15:55:49.012'  ]  ,  'ECG1':[-5.19  , -5.19  ,-5.19  ] ,  'ECG2':[-5.19  ,-5.19  ,-5.19  ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

then I want datetime time for the column Time

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

So I can use the floor method to get time only up to minutes

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.floor('s')
```

If you have duplicated rows you can remove them with drop_duplicates method

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

My output:
[image]

Comment: This solution has the same problem, you will end up with multiple entries per second as soon as the measurement values for ECG1 and ECG2 switch within a second interval.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing looks like a resampling question. De-duplicating, or only taking just the maximum value every second, is not the way I would treat a time series.

Below I create a series of data of 500 data points over a 2-second interval. This will create about 1 data point every 4 milliseconds.

Moving to a second interval can now be simply done by using [resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dummy data
df= pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.date_range(start="1/1/2020 10:00:00", end="1/1/2020 10:00:02", periods=500)})
df['ECG1'] = np.array([[i]*100 for i in [5.19, 5.2, 5.21, 5.22, 5.23]]).flatten()
df['ECG2'] = df['ECG1']+0.1
print(df.head(5))

# resample to 1s intervalls, taking the mean over the 1-s period
new_df = df.set_index('time').resample("1s").mean()
print(new_df)
```

This yields:

```
                           time  ECG1  ECG2
0 2020-01-01 10:00:00.000000000  5.19  5.29
1 2020-01-01 10:00:00.004008016  5.19  5.29
2 2020-01-01 10:00:00.008016032  5.19  5.29
3 2020-01-01 10:00:00.012024048  5.19  5.29
4 2020-01-01 10:00:00.016032064  5.19  5.29
                         ECG1      ECG2
time                                   
2020-01-01 10:00:00  5.198000  5.298000
2020-01-01 10:00:01  5.221968  5.321968
2020-01-01 10:00:02  5.230000  5.330000
```